# Groupwise sorting with SQL

Tags: sql, sorting, db2

I need to sort data groupwise. For my knowledge this can not be achieved with `sort` by multiple conditions and also a `group` does not what I need, as I don't want to reduce the records but sort them while keeping groups together. Look at the following data:

```
Group Data1 Data2 
a      1      5       
a      2      4       
a      3      7       
a      4      6       
b      1      9       
b      2      2       
b      3      1       
b      4     13       
c      1      8       
c      2     10       
c      3     13       
c      4     12
```

I want the groups to stay together, then sort by `Data2 desc` and then by  `Data1 desc`. To keep them together, after the first record of any group follows the rest with the same group, sorted the same way. Think of it that the group gets sorted by `max Data2 desc,max Data1 desc` instead of alphabetically.

```
Group Data1 Data2
b      4     13  
b      1      9  
b      2      2  
b      3      1  
c      3     13  
c      4     12  
c      2     10  
c      1      8  
a      3      7  
a      4      6  
a      1      5  
a      2      4
```

Can I achieve this with SQL?

In an other environment I could define a comperator and then simply sort by Group, Data2, Data1.

Comment: "Now I want the groups stay together, then sort by Data2 desc and then by Data1 desc so the result shouold be:" And why the group b, c and a order why not a, b ,c for example?.. And which MySQL version do you use? `SELECT VERSION();`  Besides using increments in columns names look suspect and a great candidate for normalisation.

Comment: if you don't have special requirements in the group ordering like i asked "And why the group b, c and a order why not a, b ,c for example".. You can do simply use `ORDER BY 
   test.group ASC
 , test.Data2 DESC
 , test.Data1 DESC`

Comment: I agree with Raymond Nijland the information provided is not succicient - please specify your requirements for column a besides it should stay together.

Comment: Still open questions... do you want b to be the first group because it has the highest data2 value (13) and c as well?

Comment: @MichaelTiefenbacher `b` has the highest record when ordered by `Data2 desc, Data1 desc` - b has (13, 4) and c has (13, 3)

Comment: "It's DB2 (as the tag) not MySQL - I corrected that" iam pretty sure IBM's db2 database also supports `ORDER BY test.group ASC , test.Data2 DESC , test.Data1 DESC` just fine.

Comment: @inetphantom What must be ordered higher: b with `(13, 4), (10, 6)` or c with `(13, 5)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use analytic functions in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
select *
from mytable
order by
  max(data2) over (partition by "Group") desc,
  max(data1) over (partition by "Group") desc,
  "Group",
  data2 desc,
  data1 desc;
```

Comment: data2 and data1 should have a "desc" at the end of the order by of your statement I guess

Comment: This works as expected. Only issue I have is that I can't use my `exists`-subselect from the selectionlist in the `max()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with a (Group, Data1, Data2 ) as (values
  ('a', 1, 5)       
, ('a', 2, 4)       
, ('a', 3, 7)       
, ('a', 4, 6)       
, ('b', 1, 9)       
, ('b', 2, 2)       
, ('b', 3, 1)       
, ('b', 4, 13)       
, ('c', 1, 8)       
, ('c', 2, 10)       
, ('c', 3, 13)       
, ('c', 4, 12)      
)
select a.*
from (
select b.*, rownumber() over(order by data2 desc, data1 desc) rn2
from (
select a.*, rownumber() over (partition by group order by data2 desc, data1 desc) rn1
from a
) b
where rn1=1
) b 
join a on a.group=b.group
order by b.rn2, a.data2 desc, a.data1 desc;
```